# Does MS Visio support sequence diagram?

Tags: visio

Does MS Visio support sequence diagram?

Comment: @StingyJack Judging by the date, 2010 at the newest.

Answer (score 47):

*File -> New -> Software and Database -> UML Model Diagram*

After that you should see the UML groups (on the left hand side bar) , which Sequence diagram should be present.

HTH someone else.

It seems only Visio 2013 and Visio 2016 are supported, according to Microsoft docs here :  [MS Office Article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-UML-sequence-diagram-c61c371b-b150-4958-b128-902000133b26)

Comment: I have Visio 2010 Standard.  It appears to be lacking "Software and Database" templates - which is where the UML Model Diagram templates are found

Comment: I too was afflicted with Office 2010 (and Windoze 7) this last summer, alas.  I guess that makes the answer "No", in this case :-(

Comment: In Visio 2013, you can just search for "sequence" and the result will be a UML Sequence Diagram.

Comment: @Roboprog Visio is not part of Office.

Answer (score 6):

Also take a look at http://softwarestencils.com/uml/index.html. I find that these stencils are much better than the provided ones and they support the newer UML constructs to boot.

Answer (score 5):

I found the Software and Database templates at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25110

Comment: It actually has 2 different files.  I found somewhere that the file ending in _U file is for US measurements.  I'm going to guess the _M is metric.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visio does support UML and Java diagram such as sequence, class and use case diagrams. You need to click on software in order for to use these diagrams.